# Getting IncompatibleClassChangeError while running shark-0.9.0 with hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: scala, shark-sql

I am getting the following error while running shark 0.9.0.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps, but interface was expected
        at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:82)
        at shark.SharkCliDriver.main(SharkCliDriver.scala)

Any solution regarding the problem is highly appreciable.

Comment: Please mention which version of hadoop are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Its a backward compatibility issue. 
This exception is raised when the version of scala-library.jar is different during compilation and execution. Make sure that you use the same library version during compiling and executing.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using hadoop 2.x version, do the below steps

find path to shark installation folder -name hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar

## remove all the hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar

check this
http://bigdataanalyze.blogspot.com/2014/03/issues-on-shark-with-cdh5-beta2-1.html

Comment: The OP's stacktrace clearly shows Scala conflicts, but your answer directs towards removing Hadoop core to avoid protobuf conflict, which is not written in Scala.